# I'm trying to create a file using FileStream but getting an exception why?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code :

```
public OptionsFile(string settings)
    {
        
        if (File.Exists(settings))
        {
            
        }
        else
        {
        FileStream fs=File.Create(settings);

        fs.Close();
        }
        
        path_exe = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath);
        Options_File = settings;
        
    }
```

On the line : FileStream fs=File.Create(settings);

For some reason it's unable to create the file .
In Form1 i did in the constructor :

```
Options_DB.Get_Video_File();
```

Now in Options_DB class using a breakpoint it's doing :

```
namespace test
{
    
    static class Options_DB
    {
        static string settings_dir;
        static string settings_file;
        static OptionsFile setting_file;
        static string path_settings;
        static string path_exe;
        static string outPutVideoFileDirectory;

        static Options_DB()
        {
            // ---  O P E N N I N G   S E T T I N G   F I L E   ;
            path_exe = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath);
            path_settings = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath);
            settings_file = "\\settings.txt";
            settings_dir = path_settings + @"\settings";
            setting_file = new OptionsFile(settings_dir + settings_file);
```

Then in the OptionsFile it's doing :

```
public OptionsFile(string settings)
    {
        
        if (File.Exists(settings))
        {
            
        }
        else
        {
        FileStream fs=File.Create(settings);

        fs.Close();
        }
        
        path_exe = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath);
        Options_File = settings;
        
    }
```

I used a breakpoint in the OptionsFile and see that settings contain the user directory with the settings.txt file but for some reason it's unable to make the line:

```
FileStream fs=File.Create(settings);
```

It stop on Form1 on the line : Options_DB.Get_Video_File();

The type initializer for 'ScreenVideoRecorder.Options_DB' threw an exception

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233036
  Message=The type initializer for 'ScreenVideoRecorder.Options_DB' threw an exception.
  Source=ScreenVideoRecorder
  TypeName=ScreenVideoRecorder.Options_DB
  StackTrace:
       at ScreenVideoRecorder.Options_DB.Get_Video_File()
       at ScreenVideoRecorder.Form1..ctor() in d:\C-Sharp\ScreenVideoRecorder\ScreenVideoRecorderWorkingVersion\Form1.cs:line 54
       at ScreenVideoRecorder.Program.Main() in d:\C-Sharp\ScreenVideoRecorder\ScreenVideoRecorderWorkingVersion\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
       HResult=-2147024893
       Message=Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\ScreenVideoRecorder\ScreenVideoRecorder\settings\settings.txt'.
       Source=mscorlib
       StackTrace:
            at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
            at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
            at System.IO.File.Create(String path)
            at DannyGeneral.OptionsFile..ctor(String settings) in d:\C-Sharp\ScreenVideoRecorder\ScreenVideoRecorderWorkingVersion\OptionsFile.cs:line 73
            at ScreenVideoRecorder.Options_DB..cctor() in d:\C-Sharp\ScreenVideoRecorder\ScreenVideoRecorderWorkingVersion\Options_DB.cs:line 29
       InnerException:
```

For some reason after following the breakpoint steps it's unable to create the FileStream .
I guess something is wrong with the line : FileStream fs=File.Create(settings);

settings contins when trying to create it :

```
"C:\\Users\\user name\\AppData\\Local\\project dir\\project dir\\settings\\settings.txt"
```

But it never create it .

Comment: `Could not find a part of the path '...\ScreenVideoRecorder\ScreenVideoRecorder\settings\settings.txt'.` That `settings` _folder_ exists?

Comment: In addition to all the correct answers: please don't concatenate paths like that. That's what [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/fyy7a5kt.aspx) is for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you read the inner exception, you can see that the issue is that the `settings` directory does not exist. You can remedy this by calling [`Directory.CreateDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx), which creates all directories and subdirectories in the specified path that do not already exist. (It does nothing if the directory does already exist.)

I would also recommend replacing your manual path concatenation with [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) calls.

```
settings_dir = Path.Combine(path_settings, "settings");
Directory.CreateDirectory(settings_dir);  // create directory

settings_file = "settings.txt";
setting_file = new OptionsFile(Path.Combine(settings_dir, settings_file));
```

Answer (score 2):

The exception is clear: The path
`"C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\ScreenVideoRecorder\ScreenVideoRecorder\settings\"`

doesn't exists.

Notice that this path is different from:

`"C:\Users\user name\AppData\Local\project dir\project dir\settings\"`

Answer (score 0):

The exception states:

Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\ScreenVideoRecorder\ScreenVideoRecorder\settings\settings.txt'

So you need to check that the file or folder exists or that you have permissions to write to that particular folder.

Comment: Since he want's to *create* that file (if it doesn't exist), it's pretty clear that the *folder* doesn't exist.